# Laravel Left Join ( get particular field ) and Group by ID

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Using Laravel 8.12

Unable to get **Printer title** details in Child Array.

### Order Table :

id, name, printer_id

### printer Table :

id, title

### Resources Table :

id. name

```
$resources = Resource::with('orders')
->leftJoin('orders', 'resources.id', '=', 'orders.resource_id')  
->leftJoin('printers', 'orders.printer_id', '=', 'printers.id') 
->select('resources.*')
->groupBy('resources.id');
```

Using this code i am getting below result. But missing "Title" in child array.

Current Output Result

```
 [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "user 2",
    "orders": [
      {
        "id": 190,
        "resource_id": "2",
        "printer_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 193,
        "resource_id": "2", 
        "printer_id": 3
      },       
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "user 3",
    "orders": [
      {
        "id": 207,
        "resource_id": "3",
        "printer_id": 3
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "user 4",
    "orders": [
      {
        "id": 466,
        "resource_id": "4",
        "printer_id": 4,
       
      },
      {
        "id": 370,
        "resource_id": "4",
        "printer_id": 5,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Required Result

```
 [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "orders": [
      {
        "id": 190,
        "resource_id": "2",
        "title": "user 2",
        "printer_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 193,
        "resource_id": "2", 
        "title": "user 3",
        "printer_id": 3
      },       
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "orders": [
      {
        "id": 207,
        "title": "user 3",
        "resource_id": "4",
        "printer_id": 3
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "orders": [
      {
        "id": 466,
        "title": "user 4",
        "resource_id": "4",
        "printer_id": 4,
       
      },
      {
        "id": 370,
        "title": "user 5",
        "resource_id": "4",
        "printer_id": 5,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Missing Printer table **"title"** in child array.

Comment: `->select('resources.*')` - have you tried removing that, so that every field is returned?

Comment: Tried not working

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run

```
$resources = Resource::with('orders.printer')->paginate(6);
```

an you will get all the data you need

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "user 2",
    "orders": [
      {
        "id": 190,
        "resource_id": "2",
        "printer_id": 2,
        "printer" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "title" : "user 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 193,
        "resource_id": "2", 
        "printer_id": 3,
        "printer" : {
          "id" : 3,
          "title" : "user 3"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Edit**

You need the `printer()` relation declared in the model `Order::class`

```
class Order extends Model {
    public function printer() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Printer::class); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not Working 

Resources.php Model File class Resource extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $guarded = ['id'];
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
    public function printers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Printer::class);
    }
}

Comment: $dataToReturn = $resources->paginate(6)->toArray();

Comment: IF i remove Pagination it  working. but i required pagination too

Comment: @Murugadas the relation used in the answer is the one in Order model, not Resource Model. Added the relation in the answer.... There is no issue in using paginate or other methods, everything works

Comment: Actually i am using above Order::class. But i am getting this error
message: "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.",

Comment: did you do it instead of the `->get()` as `$resources = Resource::with('orders.printer')->paginate(6)->toarray();`